# WPF Media Kit Plays DVD Garbled

Tags: wpf, media-player, wpf-mediakit

I'm using the [WPF Media Kit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/), but when I try and play a DVD, its all garbled.

[image: Garbled :(]

How do I fix this? Do I need to install a codec or something?

**EDIT**

Some extra info that *might possibly* be helpful

- Windows 7 Home Edition, 32 bit
- 2 gig ram, dualcore, 1.60 GHz each
- The DVD is Toy Story 3 (its a DVD, not the digital copy)

Comment: I've posted at http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/discussions/275601 some weeks ago. Maybe we could discuss it again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not supper familiar with WPF Media Kit, but that looks similar to what usually happens when a Copy Protected DVD is played and the decoder can't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If it plays fine in a normal DVD player application like PowerDVD or even in something like VLC Player, then it could because DVD manufacturers pull all sorts of tricks these days to prevent digital copying of DVDs. They muck about with the encoding, the filesystem, etc. to confuse computers, as long as normal players still work.

Comment: Hm... yes, it does play fine in PowerDVD and Windows Media Player... Thats kind of a shame :/